# Breeze cannot proccess metadata from oData for C# Identity entity

Tags: c#, odata, breeze, asp.net-web-api2, claims-based-identity

My oData service is generatind the metadata above. And my breeze client couldnt proccess.

Breeze error: "Metadata query failed for /odata/v1/$metadata; Unable to process returned metadata: Cannot read property 'end' of null"

Url from metadata: /odata/v1/$metadata#Users

This problem occurs only with Indentity entities! If i change it for another entity of my model it works perfectly!

Can anyone help me!?

```
<edmx:Edmx xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx" Version="1.0">
<edmx:DataServices     xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"     m:DataServiceVersion="3.0" m:MaxDataServiceVersion="3.0">
<Schema xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm" Namespace="FatoresWebV2.Models">
<EntityType Name="User">
<Key>
<PropertyRef Name="Id"/>
</Key>
<Property Name="Status" Type="Edm.Boolean" Nullable="false"/>
<Property Name="Email" Type="Edm.String"/>
<Property Name="EmailConfirmed" Type="Edm.Boolean" Nullable="false"/>
<Property Name="PasswordHash" Type="Edm.String"/>
<Property Name="SecurityStamp" Type="Edm.String"/>
<Property Name="PhoneNumber" Type="Edm.String"/>
<Property Name="PhoneNumberConfirmed" Type="Edm.Boolean" Nullable="false"/>
<Property Name="TwoFactorEnabled" Type="Edm.Boolean" Nullable="false"/>
<Property Name="LockoutEndDateUtc" Type="Edm.DateTime"/>
<Property Name="LockoutEnabled" Type="Edm.Boolean" Nullable="false"/>
<Property Name="AccessFailedCount" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false"/>
<Property Name="Id" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false"/>
<Property Name="UserName" Type="Edm.String"/>
<NavigationProperty Name="Roles" Relationship="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.FatoresWebV2_Models_User_Roles_Microsoft_AspNet_Identity_EntityFramework_IdentityUserRole_RolesPartner" ToRole="Roles" FromRole="RolesPartner"/>
<NavigationProperty Name="Claims" Relationship="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.FatoresWebV2_Models_User_Claims_Microsoft_AspNet_Identity_EntityFramework_IdentityUserClaim_ClaimsPartner" ToRole="Claims" FromRole="ClaimsPartner"/>
<NavigationProperty Name="Logins"     Relationship="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.FatoresWebV2_Models_User_Logins_Microsoft_AspNet_Identity_EntityFramework_IdentityUserLogin_LoginsPartner" ToRole="Logins" FromRole="LoginsPartner"/>
</EntityType>
</Schema>
<Schema xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm"     Namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework">
<EntityType Name="IdentityUserClaim">
<Key>
<PropertyRef Name="Id"/>
</Key>
<Property Name="Id" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false"/>
<Property Name="UserId" Type="Edm.String"/>
<Property Name="ClaimType" Type="Edm.String"/>
<Property Name="ClaimValue" Type="Edm.String"/>
</EntityType>
<EntityType Name="IdentityUserLogin">
<Property Name="LoginProvider" Type="Edm.String"/>
<Property Name="ProviderKey" Type="Edm.String"/>
<Property Name="UserId" Type="Edm.String"/>
</EntityType>
<EntityType Name="IdentityUserRole">
<Property Name="UserId" Type="Edm.String"/>
<Property Name="RoleId" Type="Edm.String"/>
</EntityType>
<Association Name="FatoresWebV2_Models_User_Roles_Microsoft_AspNet_Identity_EntityFramework_IdentityUserRole_RolesPartner">
<End Type="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUserRole" Role="Roles" Multiplicity="*"/>
<End Type="FatoresWebV2.Models.User" Role="RolesPartner" Multiplicity="0..1"/>
</Association>
<Association Name="FatoresWebV2_Models_User_Claims_Microsoft_AspNet_Identity_EntityFramework_IdentityUserClaim_ClaimsPartner">
<End Type="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUserClaim" Role="Claims" Multiplicity="*"/>
<End Type="FatoresWebV2.Models.User" Role="ClaimsPartner" Multiplicity="0..1"/>
</Association>
<Association Name="FatoresWebV2_Models_User_Logins_Microsoft_AspNet_Identity_EntityFramework_IdentityUserLogin_LoginsPartner">
<End Type="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUserLogin" Role="Logins"     Multiplicity="*"/>
<End Type="FatoresWebV2.Models.User" Role="LoginsPartner" Multiplicity="0..1"/>
</Association>
</Schema>
<Schema xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm" Namespace="Default">
<EntityContainer Name="Container" m:IsDefaultEntityContainer="true">
<EntitySet Name="Users" EntityType="FatoresWebV2.Models.User"/>
<EntitySet Name="IdentityUserClaims"     EntityType="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUserClaim"/>
<EntitySet Name="IdentityUserLogins"     EntityType="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUserLogin"/>
<EntitySet Name="IdentityUserRoles" EntityType="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUserRole"/>
<AssociationSet Name="FatoresWebV2_Models_User_Roles_Microsoft_AspNet_Identity_EntityFramework_IdentityUserRole_RolesPartnerSet" Association="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.FatoresWebV2_Models_User_Roles_Microsoft_AspNet_Identity_EntityFramework_IdentityUserRole_RolesPartner">
<End Role="RolesPartner" EntitySet="Users"/>
<End Role="Roles" EntitySet="IdentityUserRoles"/>
</AssociationSet>
<AssociationSet Name="FatoresWebV2_Models_User_Claims_Microsoft_AspNet_Identity_EntityFramework_IdentityUserClaim_ClaimsPartnerSet" Association="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.FatoresWebV2_Models_User_Claims_Microsoft_AspNet_Identity_EntityFramework_IdentityUserClaim_ClaimsPartner">
<End Role="ClaimsPartner" EntitySet="Users"/>
<End Role="Claims" EntitySet="IdentityUserClaims"/>
</AssociationSet>
<AssociationSet Name="FatoresWebV2_Models_User_Logins_Microsoft_AspNet_Identity_EntityFramework_IdentityUserLogin_LoginsPartnerSet" Association="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.FatoresWebV2_Models_User_Logins_Microsoft_AspNet_Identity_EntityFramework_IdentityUserLogin_LoginsPartner">
<End Role="LoginsPartner" EntitySet="Users"/>
<End Role="Logins" EntitySet="IdentityUserLogins"/>
</AssociationSet>
</EntityContainer>
</Schema>
</edmx:DataServices>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

Comment: Can you try with OData v2 or v3?